# Why can't I SELECT * FROM the view I just created?

Tags: sql-server

I created a view

```
CREATE VIEW BenefitsView AS SELECT * FROM Benefits
```

I get a message saying this ran successfully.
Then I try to select everything from that view

```
SELECT * FROM BenefitsView
```

but I'm getting a an error:

> saying `BenefitsView` is an invalid object name?

Why? Also I've tried to find the view in the object explorer but can't?

Comment: does `CREATE VIEW AS BenefitsView FROM Benefits` actually execute successfully? It doesn't look like a complete SQL statement. you're saying the view `BenefitsView` is `From Benefits` but that's not a thing.

Comment: The first sample is not valid; I'm not sure how it could have run it. But assuming it's just a typo missing the `SELECT *`, I suspect the problem is you also need to grant permissions.

Comment: Yah my bad it was just a typo. How would I grant a permission to that view. Because I know its there. When I try to recreate it, it says it already exits

Answer (score 0):

Just check if u have created in correct schema and database !

If not correct it , also check permission there for logon you are executing the select statement if not run `grant select to <objectName>` where object name is your table name `Benefits`

Also grant permission must be executed from user which has rights to do that !

Comment: I'm new to sql and ssms. So please know that I really don't know how to check the schema(Though I know this view was created and its in the correct database) And I don't know how to check permissions. I'm just following the instructions out of my text book. please explain how to navigate to these possible solutions in lamen terms

Comment: @Randy
try putting `sp_help Benefits` -> it should show object type as table
`sp_help BenefitsView` -> should show you object type as view .

Also check under which schema this is created in above result .